# Where should I put a custom javascript module so that it can be found by the browser

Tags: node.js, npm

My project file structure is like the following:

[image]

`config.js` is a module that I want to share between the client and the server.

In the server side file `app.js`, I wrote `var config = require('./config');` and the module can be correctly found and included. I also wrote `app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));` so that files in the folder `client` are served to the clients.

However, in the client side html file `index.html`, I wrote

```
<script src="/config/config.js"></script>
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

but both of them results in 404 Not found error. Where should I put `config.js` and how can I include it in the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation :

Your `config.js` is actually unreachable by your client. By doing

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client')));
```

you tell your app to look inside the `client` folder for requested url and to serve files matching url.
(E.g. accessing `http://127.0.0.1/ref.html` will result in your app looking for a file named `ref.html` within the `client` folder. If found, it will simply be sent back to. Otherwise, you will face a `404`.)

Knowing this, we can conclude that

```
<script src="/config/config.js"></script>
```

won't find anything. It will look for a folder `config` in `client` but won't see it. Here comes the first `404`.

On the same way,

```
<script src="config.js"></script>
```

will ask for a file named `config.js` **inside** your `client` folder. Another `404`.

### Resolution :

You could simply put it in the `client` folder and change your `var config = require('./config');` to `var config = require('./client/config');`.

You would then be able to use `<script src="/config.js"></script>` in your html. (Notice the `/` I added to the path. That's because you want it to be found at the root of your website.)

Comment: I use to think that all modules should reside in under /node_modules, your explanation clears things a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Usually, `node_modules` is meant for [npm modules](https://www.npmjs.com/). It is a folder generated from your `package.json` file when you do `npm install`. Everything within this folder is expected to be retrievable at any moment. It is not meant for custom/personal code. Moreover, this folder should **never** be commited/pushed/sent with your project.